# Is there a way to do conditional matrix loop using 'continue'

Tags: matrix

[image]I have the following:

```
n = 3;
m = 5;
ww = RandomReal[{0, 0.1}, {n, n}];
uu = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {m, n}];
pp = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
ss = RandomInteger[{0, 5}, {m, n}];
Grid[{{"ww", "uu", "pp", "ss"}, {ww // TableForm, uu // TableForm, 
   pp // TableForm, ss // TableForm}}, Spacings -> {5, 2}, 
 Dividers -> All]
```

where I would like to look at every element of matrix `ss` and produce a matrix `tt`, with zeroes at the locations in `ss` which have zeroes, and in all other positions do the following:

```
tt = (-1/Subscript[ww, m]) Log[(1 - uu)/(Subscript[pp, m - 1])],
```

where `Subscript[ww, m]` is the value at `index` of `ww` matrix and where `Subscript[pp, m - 1]` is the value at `index-1` of `pp` matrix.

So for example if the first value ever read from matrix `ss` happens to be 2, then value taken from matrix `ww` would be from the row 2, but from `pp` would be from row 1.

Also how to tell difference between a 0 as a valid value from within the matrix elements to end of matrix if I do not know the actual size of the matrix beforehand?

Given the data as above, tt matrix would be like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi @kguler. Thanks for editing but not sure how can someone else edit my post? :)

Comment: I'm a little unclear about what `tt` is intended to do. As it is presented `tt` has a small syntax error, the training comma. Secondly `Subscript[ww,m]` is a formatted object with `ww` displayed with a typographical subscript `m`. Your text suggests that it is the value at `index` of `ww`. Does `index` refer to `m`?  If the value in `ss` is 2 then the "value" to be taken from `ww` would be from row 2. Do you mean all of row 2 or some particular element in row 2, if so which element ?

Comment: @sebastiancheung see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq#editing)

Comment: Hi @image_doctor, I just added what matrix tt would look like using the input data prescribed. i.e, looking at 2nd column 1st row of ss value at 2: gives (-1/ww22)Log(1-uu12)/pp12)=(-1/0.05565)Log(1-0.8498)/0.490 = 21.25. Similarly 3rd column, 1st row of ss, take corresponding value from element uu13 (0.5322), with value of 3 means take value of ww33 (0.053) and pp23 (0.882) = 11.93

Comment: Can I clarify, is it the case that you want an output matrix, which has scalar values at each position and not an output matrix which has a matrix `tt` of zeroes at each position in which `ss` has a zero and a scalar value `tt` at other positions?

Comment: Hi @image_doctor, I think I solved it (below), using kguler's template, I padded the matrix ww with additional row and level shifted the tt formula from tt = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; ss[[i, j]] != 0 :>
   (-1/ww[[ss[[i, j]], j]]) Log[(1 - uu[[i, j]])/ pp[[ss[[i, j]] - 1, j]]], {m, n}] to become tt = SparseArray[ {i_, j_} /; ss[[i, j]] != 0 :> (-1/ww[[ss[[i, j]] + 1, j]]) Log[(1 - uu[[i, j]])/ pp[[ss[[i, j]], j]]], {20, 5} ] because the references to pp matrix cannot go below 1 when a value of 1 is presented in ss matrix. I know not easy to visualize but if you goto kguler answer then my final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two gaps in the information provided in the question :
First, the elements of `ss` cannot be greater than 3 (row dimension of `ww` and `pp`).
Second, how do you process the case `ss[[i, j]] = 1` ? (Which row of `pp` do you use?)
You need to change the rule so that either ss does not contain any `1`s or treat the `1`s as you treat `0`s. In the following I restricted `ss` to values in `{0, 2, 3}`.

```
n = 3; m = 5;
ww = RandomReal[{0, 0.1}, {n, n}];
uu = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {m, n}];
pp = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
ss = RandomChoice[{0, 2, 3}, {m, n}];
```

Define `tt` as

```
tt = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; ss[[i, j]] != 0 :>
   (-1/ww[[ss[[i, j]], j]]) Log[(1 - uu[[i, j]])/ pp[[ss[[i, j]] - 1, j]]], {m, n}]
```

With this,

```
Grid[Transpose@{{"ww", "uu", "pp", "ss", "tt"}, 
  TableForm /@ {ww, uu, pp, ss, Normal[tt]}}, Spacings -> {5, 2}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Incorporating OP's latest clarifications:

```
ww2 = Prepend[ww, {a, b, c}];
f2[i_, j_] := (-1/ww2[[ss[[i, j]] + 1, j]]) Log[(1 - uu[[i, j]])/pp[[ss[[i, j]], j]]];
tt2 = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; ss[[i, j]] != 0 :> f2[i, j], {m, n}];
Grid[Transpose@{{"uu", "ww", "pp", "ss", "ww2", "tt2"}, 
    TableForm /@ {uu, ww, pp, ss, ww2, Normal[tt2]}},
 Spacings -> {5, 2}, 
 Dividers -> {{All, {1 -> Thick, -1 -> Thick}}, 
              {All, {5 -> Thick, 1 -> Thick, -1 -> Thick}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @kguler, Well spotted! Therefore pp matrix has to have one more row greater than matrix ww, I filled it with 1 1 1, so that if elements within ss happens to be value of 1, tt has to go one more row back.

Comment: Hi @kguler, how long you have been using Mathematica? Seems like you know everything there is about it? It is the solution I am looking for. In that case what do you need to modify? Great Help :)

Comment: sebastian, adding a row of `1`s to `pp` will not work --you still would be referring to `pp[[0,j]]` when the corresponding element in `ss` is `1`. You can leave `1`s in `ss` instead. (I have been using Mma off and on version 1; but only after version 6 it has become my main tool/toy.)

Comment: @sebastian, I meant _define `tt` so that `tt[[i,j]]=ss[[i,j]` if `ss[[[i,j]]=0` **or** `ss[[i,j]]=1`_. That is, change the part inside `SparseArray` following `:>` to `If[ss[[i, j]] == 1, 1, (-1/ww[[ss[[i, j]], j]]) Log[(1 - uu[[i, j]])/ pp[[ss[[i, j]] - 1, j]]]]`. This should work when "`1`s are present in `ss`".

Comment: Hi @kguler, possible to work with pp with one more row than ww as well as evaluating when ss has elements containing 1s?

Comment: Hi @kguler Could you clarify? Seem to have syntax error? Still need to treat 1's just like any other non-zero values, can't have 1's to be treated the same as 0's.

Comment: This is for testing, I think the real data size would be ww = 5 x 5, uu = 1000 x 5, pp = 6 x 5, ss = 1000 x 5 and tt would be 1000 x 5 too.

Comment: Hi @kguler So instead, can we count backward instead so when ss has elements of 1s, it can still reference the correct location?

Comment: Hi @kuler, I think easiest is simply to pad ww matrix with an additional rows (dont care what values), and then shift up the for formula tt so that it becomes tt = SparseArray[ {i_, j_} /;
    ss[[i, j]] != 
     0 :> (-1/ww[[ss[[i, j]] + 1, j]]) Log[(1 - uu[[i, j]])/
      pp[[ss[[i, j]], j]]], {20, 5} ]

Comment: @sebastiancheung Thank you for that clarification.

Comment: Hi @kguler. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

`MapIndexed` might be what you are looking for.  For example, start with a matrix of zero and non-zero elements:

```
s = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]
```

> `{{0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}`

And another matrix of stuff:

```
instead = Table[w[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]
```

> `{{w[1, 1], w[1, 2], w[1, 3]}, {w[2, 1], w[2, 2], w[2, 3]}, {w[3, 1], 
>     w[3, 2], w[3, 3]}}`

The use `MapIndexed` to trawl through and substitute as required:

```
MapIndexed[If[#1 == 0, #1, instead[[Sequence @@ #2]]] &, s, {2}]
```

> `{{0, w[1, 2], w[1, 3]}, {0, w[2, 2], 0}, {w[3, 1], w[3, 2], w[3, 3]}}`

This goes through each element of s, if it's zero keep it as it is, if not use the current index to pull something out of another matrix.

Comment: Hi @wxffles very fast response and it seems to work, though not exactly what I asked for, but could be adapted. Also what is this last argument levelspec set to 2 does?

Comment: @sebastiancheung The `{2}` is to map on to exactly the elements that are 2 levels deep.  Just what you need for a 2D matrix.  I was a little hazy on exactly what you required, but confident it could be adapted.  You can of course modify the index `#2` before you use it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which uses replacement rules. It looks at each element in a matrix and replaces it with something based upon the value of the element.

Define a function which can be used to replace an element based on the values of matrices defined in some global variables ( here we take the row referred to by element from `ww` and `pp`):

```
f[element_]:=ww[[element]] + pp[[element]]
```

Define an arbitrary array of zeroes, the size of this could be based on the value of element if desired:

```
zeroes = ConstantArray[0,{2,2}]
```

Replace elements of matrix `ss` with things based on the value of its elements:

```
ss /. {0 :> zeroes, elem_?Positive :>f[elem]}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The entire solution could be condensed to by abstracting out the auxiliary functions:

```
  ss /. {0 :>  ConstantArray[0,{2,2}], elem_?Positive :> ww[[elem]] + pp[[elem]] }
```

**Update based on clarifications to original question:**

Both the following solutions build an intermediate matrix, merging a value from `ss` with its indices, of the form {{{ss[[1,1]],1,1},{ss[[1,2]],1,2},...},{...},{...,{ss[[m,n]],m,n}}}

An outline solution in which `myFunc` takes the place of whatever needs to be done in case of a non-zero element in `ss`.

A function based on element indices from `ss`:

```
myFunc[i_, j_] := {i^2, j^2}
```

**Solution using replacement rules**

Derive a new matrix from the elements of `ss`

```
tt=Array[{ss[[#1, #2]], #1, #2} &, Dimensions@ss] /.
 {{0, _, _} :> 0, {a_?Positive, b_, c_} :> myFunc @@ {b, c}}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Solution using `Apply`**

Define what to do to each element:

```
myFunc[0, i_, j_] := 0
myFunc[val_, i_, j_] := {i^2, j^2}
```

Apply the function to `ss`:

```
Apply[myFunc, Array[{ss[[#1, #2]], #1, #2} &, Dimensions@ss], {2}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi @image_doctor, this is very similar to kguler solution?

Comment: Yes, broadly similar in that they both use replacement rules. I've updated the solution in light of your clarifications and added an alternate using `Apply`.