# How to take matrix elements as input to another matrix or loop?

Tags: matrix

Say I have matrix tmp1 of size 1000 x 5 (shown is just a small section for illustration purpose), consisting of real numbers[image] and 0:

How can I iteratively take every non-zero real number elements and use it as input for another 'For' loop argument limit to calculate another set of matrix values? For example, taking second row, first column value of 4.956 I would like to use it to calculate a 'For' loop like

r=0.4;

For[i = 0, i < **4.956**, i = i + 0.2,

calculate P = Exp[-r i]*i

P += P

And place this cumulated P result into tmp2 output matrix at same corresponding location as where 4.956 was taken from. Then repeat for the next non-zero element of tmp1, so for row 2, column 2 value of 1.234:

For[i = 0, i < **1.234**, i = i + 0.2,

calculate P = Exp[-r i]*i

P += P

and result into tmp2 location row 2, column 2. Any zero elements found in tmp1 will simply be mapped to tmp2 of same location. Thanks.

Comment: Did  you consider the answers from this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14262/is-there-a-way-to-do-conditional-matrix-loop-using-continue?

Comment: For any question you ask, below the voting arrows is a checkmark. If you find an answer the most useful of the one's you received, click on the check mark. It then turns green, like on [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14344/52) to one of your questions. Note, your selection is not set in stone, if another answer comes along that is better, you can change it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a bit of functional programming. Here I'm fixing `r` to be 3 for readability.

```
With[{r = 3}, 
   Map[(#.Exp[-r*#]) &[Range[0, #, .2]] &, tmp1, {2}]
]

(*{{0., 0., 0.}, {0.539181, 0.484569, 0.534811}, {0.484569, 0., 
  0.539174}, {0., 0., 0.484569}}*)
```

This is likely quite a bit faster than anything you are going to get with `For` loops unless you use `Compile`. Here's a benchmark.

```
tmp = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {10^5, 10}]*RandomReal[{0, 5}, {10^5, 10}];

With[{r = 3}, 
   Map[(#.Exp[-r*#]) &[Range[0, #, .2]] &, 
    tmp, {2}]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{1.160002, Null}*)
```

**Edit:**

In response to the comments.  Here is one way to do this using `ReplaceAll`. Note that it is about 10 times slower than using `Map`.

```
With[{r = 3},
   SetAttributes[fn, Listable];
   fn[m_] := (#.Exp[-r*#]) &[Range[0, m, .2]];
   tmp /. m_ :> fn[m]
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{10.6900150, Null}*)
```

Finally, if you really want a more procedural approach you can use `Compile` with loops. I've pulled out all the stops here to make it fast. If you have a C compiler installed you could additionally try setting the `CompilationTarget` to "C".

```
f = Compile[{{r, _Real}, {tmp, _Real, 2}},
   Block[{g, rng, u, v, out = Internal`Bag[], res},
    {v, u} = Dimensions[tmp];
    Do[
     rng = Range[0., Compile`GetElement[tmp, i, j], .2];
     res = rng.Exp[-r*rng];
     Internal`StuffBag[out, res]
     , {i, v}, {j, u}
     ];
    Partition[Internal`BagPart[out, All], u]
    ], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Note that this didn't make things much faster and the functional approach is in my opinion much cleaner.

```
f[3., tmp]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.9984018, Null}*)
```

Comment: Hi @Andy Ross, the last {2} is the levelspec? Not sure how that affects the results?

Comment: Thank @Andy Ross works well, not sure if I want to use Replacement rule instead of Map when working with large data set later.

Comment: Yes, the {2} is the levelspec. I recommend using `Map[f, Array[Subscript[x, ##] &, {5, 5}], lspec]` with different `lspecs` to see what this does.

Comment: Hi @Andy Ross, so how to modify your solution to use Replacement instead of Map? Performance seems faster using it as image_doctor pointed out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 approaches to appling a function to a 2D list ( matrix ) of scalar values.

```
myFunc[x_] := x^2

matrix = RandomInteger[Range@2, {4, 5}];
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Listable Function Attribute**

```
SetAttributes[myFunc, Listable]

myFunc@matrix
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Map**

As Andy Ross has illustrated you can use `Map`.

```
Map[myFunc, matrix, {2}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Replacement Rule(s)**

```
Clear@m
matrix /. m_ -> myFunc[m]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Speed**

Define a larger matrix of 10^7 elements, apply the function and measure the `AbsoluteTiming`.

```
matrix = RandomInteger[Range@2, {1000, 10000}];
Grid[{{"Map", "Listable", "Replacement"}, 
{ Map[myFunc, matrix, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming,
  Clear@m; myFunc@matrix; // AbsoluteTiming,
  matrix /. m_ -> myFunc[m]; // AbsoluteTiming}
 [[All, 1]]
}, Dividers -> All]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi @image_doctor could you share the code for coding the last part of AbsoluteTiming? Thanks

Comment: @sebastiancheung Yes of course, on re-running it I noticed a small error which changes the results so that Listable and Replacement are now much closer in performance.

Comment: Your choice of `x^2` for `myFunc` makes these timings a little misleading. You should try a function that isn't already listable like, for example, `myFunc[x_] := Total[Range[x]]`. It is worth looking at `TracePrint` of your Replacement example to see why this matters.

Comment: @AndyRoss Perhaps it makes more sense to call the 3rd option  Replacement + Listable.